# The limit as x approaches infinity of a polynomial over e^x

Tags: limits, polynomials

Given the equation:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left[{p(x)\over e^{x}}\right] $$

where $ p(x) $ is a polynomial, is the limit always 0?
My colleagues assume yes, but I don't see why the polynomial couldn't be:
$$ p(x)=e^{|x|}x^{2}+e^{|x|}x$$
In which case the limit should approach $\infty$.

Comment: Because that's not a Polynomial :) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial

Comment: That's what they said too, but why not?

Comment: This is coherent question with a well-defined answer. Does the question reflect a misunderstanding of a definition? Yes. Does that make the question of poor quality? Certainly not. Do we want to discourage (by downvoting) people from posting questions when they misunderstand a definition? That doesn't reflect my values, nor is it aligned with an apparent goal of this site, which is to spread and archive mathematics knowledge.

Comment: @rajb245 in general, I agree with you. However, check out the Mathematics Meta. You will QUICKLY realize that different people have completely different criteria for voting. Some just upvote, some just downvote, some downvote anytime they think the question could be answered with a simple lookup, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial cannot be what you want it to be because that's no polynomial. By definition, a polynomial in one variable $x$ over $\Bbb R$ is a finite sum of natural powers of $x$, with coefficients that are *real numbers*. $e^x$ is not a real number, and thus is not a valid coefficient. You are allowed to use things like $e^2, \sqrt 5, \pi$ and a lot of other cool numbers as coefficients, but you are allowed to do that precicely because in the end, that's exactly what they are: numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomials are ***defined*** as
$$\sum_{k=0}^n c_k x^k$$  Where $n$ is an integer and $c_k$ are constants depending on $k$.  Note that $e^x \neq cx^k$ for *any* constant $c$ and integer $k$